# Rails nested category list (parent > child) using association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, nested, associations

I have category in 3 levels. At the moment the association as check_box is giving me 1 level list so it is impossible to tell if I'm selecting a level 3 item from which level 1.

- Level 1

  - Level 2

    - Level 3

Is there a way to list my categories in Parent > Child type of grouped indentation?

```
<%= f.association :categories, :include_blank => false, as: :check_boxes, label: false %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a class for the checkboxes based on the level that they are in and place the categories based on the applied class.

```
category-level-0 {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
category-level-1 {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
category-level-2 {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
}
```